# Calling/Subscribing to a function with parameters, that returns an observable

Tags: rxjs

This is somewhat related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074467/rxjs-mergeall-scan-coninutes-to-accumulate/71074508#71074508) I asked. The feature$ function in that question returns an observable with a map that uses the parameter passed to the function:

```
 feature$ = (feature: string): Observable<FeatureConfig | null> => {
    return this.features$.pipe(
      map((features: FeatureConfig[]) => {
        return (
          features.find((featureConfig: FeatureConfig) => {
            return featureConfig.key === feature;
          })?.value ?? null
        );
      })
    );
  };
```

This is then used like this elsewhere:

```
this.featureService
  .feature$("featureName")
  .subscribe((featureConfig: FeatureConfig) => {
    ...
  });
```

Or:

```
someFeature$ = this.featureService.feature$("featureName");
```

The features$ observable is (I think, by definition) a hot observable as its value can change throughout the life of the observable and it never completes. While this seems to work for its intended purpose, I am just wondering what the effect this has when there are many subscribers to that feature$ function. I fear there  might be some unintended behavior that I am not immediately noticing.

Is this a bad pattern in general? And if so, is there a better pattern to do something similar? That is, subscribe to an observable created with a parameter passed to a function.

For example, would something like this be preferred?

```
  feature$ = (featureName: string): Observable<FeatureConfig | null> => {
    return of(featureName).pipe(
      mergeMap((feature: string) => combineLatest([of(feature), this.features$])),
      map(([feature, features]: [string, FeatureConfig[]]) => {
        return (
          features.find((featureConfig: FeatureConfig) => {
            return featureConfig.key === feature;
          })?.value ?? null
        );
      })
    );
  };
```

Or does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the second stream example is a bit overly complicated, your `features$$` is a Behavior subject that might continuously updating itself. Your intend is only take in parameter and process through the features array and output the found feature, the first form of the code is more appropriate.

As the source stream is a `BehaviorSubject` you will always have a value once subscribe(), just don't forget to unsubcribe() to prevent memory leak. Alternatively use `take(1)` or `first()` operator before `subscribe()`

When you create an observable from a function you get a new instance of that stream, it is a hot observable but not `shared()`, so filtering on 'featureA' wouldn't affect result on filtering on 'featureB', and yes `of()` and `combineLatest()` really does nothing in your use case, as those are static and unchange function param

Comment: Yea I always use takeUntil and a local Subject with OnDestroy in components, or take(1)/first() otherwise where these things are used. I just wasn't sure about using the value from the function parameter (feature: string) inside the observable like that. I just wanted to make sure that wasn't doing anything weird. Like if I subscribed once for "featureA" is that somehow affecting another "featureB" subscription in some way that is not obvious? I havent noticed anything specific, but wrapping the parameter in an of() there doesn't really benefit this at all, and the first should be ok, right?

Comment: When you create an observable from a function you get a new instance of that stream, it is a hot observable but not shared(), so filtering on 'featureA' wouldn't affect result on filtering on 'featureB', and yes of() and combineLatest() really does nothing in your use case, as those are static and unchange function param

Comment: Awesome that answers my question, thanks!!! You should add that comment to your answer. ;)

Comment: no worries, added to answer